# Should Game Center be Optional?

Tags: ios, game-center

This question may be a little vague / philosophical, but what do you do when a user doesn't want to use Game Center?

Normally you run authenticateWithCompletionHandler: when your app starts. But what if your user doesn't have a Game Center account? Do they then get nagged each launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little testing, it looks like the user is nagged only 3 times. After the third, they need to sign in via Game Center app. (I haven't seen any of this documented, hence the original question, and my uncertainty about the answer.)